# Dynamically determine aggregate KeyBounds in GeoTrellis

Tags: scala, gis, geotrellis

Given an `RDD[(SpatialKey, Tile)]` in GeoTrellis, how do I compute the aggregate `KeyBounds[SpatialKey]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any `RDD[(K, V])]` where K is [Boundable](http://geotrellis.github.io/scaladocs/0.10/#geotrellis.spark.Boundable), i.e. there is an implicit `Boundable[K]` in scope, you can do:

```
val bounds: KeyBounds[K] =
  tiles.map({ case (key, _) => KeyBounds(key, key) }).reduce(_ combine _)
```

This will work over `SpatialKey` and `SpaceTimeKey`, as GeoTrellis provides the implicit Boundable typeclasses for those types. So in your case,

```
val bounds: KeyBounds[SpatialKey] =
  tiles.map({ case (key, _) => KeyBounds(key, key) }).reduce(_ combine _)
```

will work.